# Query para mostrar dos filas de una misma tabla MySQL

Tags: mysql

Quiero ver dos filas de una misma tupla pero no sé cómo

Comment: Hola TheLasthought. Poco podemos ayudarte si no das más información de las tablas, digo yo...

Comment: y como quieres verlas? juntas, separadas, divorciadas, mezcladas, arriba, abajo? Si nos lo especificas sera mejor para ambos

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Muéstranos qué has intentado. Date una vuelta [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.